# Include custom PHP in Drupal 7 template

Tags: php, templates, drupal

I make a class to generate templates for Drupal 7. The problem is that I have a template file with all my variables shown, but when I "render" by include this template, it doesn't show it in Drupal environment (no CSS/JS).

So is there a way to tell Drupal to show this file like it was a custom module template ? I can't use `theme('MY_THEME', array());` because this is NOT a module, and the variables are not always the same.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution was indeed to create a module, that implements the hook_theme(), and use this to render the template from my class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass pass you variable in drupal theme hook like this

```
theme ('youtheme', array('data' => $_GET));
```

Then use you date

```
$items['youtheme'] = array(
    'template'  => 'yourtemplatename',
    'path'      => drupal_get_path ('module', 'youmodulename') . '/templates/',
);
```

You can access the `$data` variable in your templates file  `yourtemplatename.tpl.php`